# How do draw text in middle of arc? (for pie chart)

Tags: java, geometry, awt, java-2d

I'm drawing a pie chart using a series of calls to `drawArc` like so:

```
g.fillArc(x, y, w, h, startAngle, arcAngle);
```

What I can't work out is how to display text in the middle of the arc, in order to display the %. Is there some equation I can use to get the center point of any arc I draw?

Comment: One (crude) way to approach this is to get a `Rectangle2D` from a `Shape` using [`getBounds2D()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Shape.html#getBounds2D()) then call `getCenterX/Y()` methods. The `Shape` itself would need to be an [`Arc2D.Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/Arc2D.Double.html) or similar.

Answer (score 3):

Center point of arc is

```
cx = x + w/2
cy = y + h/2
```

Middle angle of arc is

```
Fi = startAngle + arcAngle/2
```

[Radius at angle Fi is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_center)  (added 0.5 due to using w/h instead of a/b)

```
r = 0.5 * w * h / Sqrt((h*Cos(Fi))^2 + (w*Sin(Fi))^2)
```

Middle point of arc is

```
mx  = cx + r * Cos(Fi)
my  = cy + r * Sin(Fi)
```

Example for

```
x = 100 y=100 w=400 h=200
start = 0 sweep = 90 degrees = Pi/2
cx = 300  cy = 200
fi  = pi/4
r = 200 * 100 / Sqrt((200^2 * 1/2 + 100^2 * 1/2)) = 
     20000 / Sqrt(20000 + 5000) = 
     20000 / 158 = 126
mx = 300 + 126 * 0.707 = 389
my = 200 + 253 * 0.707 = 289
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Fi = startAngle + arcAngle/2 ` instead be `Fi = (startAngle + arcAngle)/2` to force the addition prior to division? Otherwise, good approach!

Comment: @Andrew Thompson No. As far as I understand, `arcAngle` is not angle for the end of arc, but covering angle  `arcAngle - the angular extent of the arc, relative to the start angle`. So `endAngle = (startAngle + arcAngle)` and `middleAngle = (startAngle + endAngle)/2 =  startAngle + arcAngle/2 `

Comment: thanks very much! Though im getting a syntax error related to the carrot (im using codenameone, should still be more or less standard java)bad operand types for binary operator '^'
        double r = w * h / Math.sqrt( (h*Math.cos(Fi))^2 + (w*Math.sin(Fi))^2 );

Comment: This is pseudocode notion for power operator. Perhaps you have `pow` function (`pow(t,2)`), but for squaring of `t` it is enough to use multiplication `t*t`

Comment: Just varable for explanation of squaring

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt seem to work, here is what I implemented for that line 'double r = w * h / Math.sqrt( MathUtil.pow(h*Math.cos(Fi), two) + MathUtil.pow(w*Math.sin(Fi), two) ); ' but the x and y coordinates are all outside of the area where my pie chart is. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to make simple example with pen and paper and compare with code calculations. P.S. I corrected cx,cy

Comment: thanks for the help, I changed x,y but still no luck. Some coords are negative and some are outside boundaries so I dont see any of the draw strings. Can you see any obvious mistakes in this code ? maybe I need some brackets around certain things but I tried all combinations. https://pastebin.com/HSBc8yXc

Comment: What about radians/degrees in Cos/Sin calls?

Comment: thanks, I tried everything and could never get it to work. I couldn't figure out why so had to give up for now, but the help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can see working example. Does the same data give wrong result with your implementation?